# OpenAPI npm cli is not generating spring code using v3 oas

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I'm generating spring server code using the below command

```sh
    openapi-generator generate -g spring -o eventspec -i pets.yaml
```

Pets.yaml is Petstore 3.0.0 yaml file.

Code is getting generated properly, however the springfox dependency is getting adding and API code is annotated with io.swagger.annotations not with io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations

Let me know if i'm missing some thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anyone has the cycle to update the template to use io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations. We welcome contributions from the community for such enhancement.

Ref: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4245